# 2D Raycasting in a grid-based environment

Tags: javascript, raycasting, pixi.js

Hello stackoverflow community.  Recently, I've been working on getting a proper raycasting system working.  Currently, I've been working entirely in 2D, with a 2D map and player representation.  I'm having issues however properly creating a grid-based environment.  I think the issue is the way I'm casting rays isn't grid-based at all.  I have an example of my issue [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/pshq0tqu9krnbgv/index.html).  As you can see, the rays appear choppy and malformed.  Can anyone give me some insight on how a grid-based system would work?  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Here's the full source code(I'm using PIXI.js for my rendering):

```
var world = [
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
        [1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
        [1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
        [1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
];

var width = world[0].length;
var height = world.length;

var scale = 8;

var posX = 1;
var posY = 1;
var yaw = 0;
var m = 0;

var renderer = new PIXI.WebGLRenderer(width * scale,height * scale);
//var renderer = new PIXI.WebGLRenderer(320,200);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0xFFFFFF);
var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
stage.addChild(graphics);

function drawMap()
{
    for(var x = 0;x < width;x++)
    {
        for(var y = 0;y < height;y++)
        {
            if(world[y][x])
            {
                graphics.beginFill(0xCCCCCC);
                graphics.drawRect(x * scale, y * scale, scale, scale);
                graphics.endFill();
            }
        }
    }
}

function drawPlayer()
{
    graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
    graphics.drawRect(posX * scale, posY * scale, 4, 4);
    graphics.endFill();

    graphics.lineStyle(1,0x000000);
    graphics.moveTo(posX * scale + 2, posY * scale + 2);
    graphics.lineTo(posX * scale + Math.cos(yaw) * 20 + 2, posY * scale + Math.sin(yaw) * 20 + 2);
}

function move()
{
    var newX = posX + Math.cos(yaw) * m * 0.3;
    var newY = posY + Math.sin(yaw) * m * 0.3;

    m = 0;

    if(isColliding(newX,newY))
    {
        return;
    }

    posX = newX;
    posY = newY;
}

function isColliding(x,y)
{
    if(world[Math.floor(y)][Math.floor(x)])
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function castRays()
{
    var rayYaw = 0;

    var rayX = posX;
    var rayY = posY;

    var dist = 0;

    for(var x = -160;x < 160;x++)
    {
        rayYaw = x * 0.1875;

        while(!isColliding(rayX,rayY))
        {
            rayX += Math.cos((rayYaw) * (Math.PI / 180) + yaw);
            rayY += Math.sin((rayYaw) * (Math.PI / 180) + yaw);

            if(rayX < 0 || rayX >= width || rayY < 0 || rayY >= height)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(posX - rayX,2) + Math.pow(posY - rayY,2));

        graphics.lineStyle(1,0x00FFCC);
        graphics.moveTo(posX * scale + 2, posY * scale + 2);
        graphics.lineTo(rayX * scale + Math.cos((rayYaw) * (Math.PI / 180)) + 2, rayY * scale + Math.sin((rayYaw) * (Math.PI / 180)) + 2);

        //drawLine(x + 160,dist);

        rayX = posX;
        rayY = posY;
    }
}

function drawLine(x,d)
{
    var slice = (32 * d / 160);

    var start = (100 - (slice/2));

    graphics.lineStyle(1,0xCCCCCC);
    graphics.moveTo(x,start);
    graphics.lineTo(x,slice);
}

function main()
{
    drawMap();
    move();
    drawPlayer();
    castRays();

    renderer.render(stage);
    graphics.clear();
}

document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == '38') 
    {
        // up arrow
        m = 1;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '40') 
    {
        // down arrow
        m = -1;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '37')
    {
        // left arrow
        yaw -= 0.1;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39')
    {
        // right arrow
        yaw += 0.1;
    }
}

setInterval(main,1000/30);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you treat your map as a matrix and isColliding() is oversimplified. You really should treat each 1 in the matrix as a square to determine if and where exactly your ray is hitting it.

I would completely re-write the castRays to more traditional raytracing approach:

```
for each point on your "screen":
  define vector V from point of view P through this point on screen
  for each line S + L*y forming sides of each square, find if your vector intersects it:
      P + V*k = S + L*y when k>0 and y is in 0..1
```

shortest k, if exists, forms your line.
There is plenty of room for optimizations as you go along this path.

**Update**

Did not want to write it all up, but here is a good article on ray-box intersection  optimization, especially if the box or rectangle is aligned to the axis: http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-7-intersecting-simple-shapes/ray-box-intersection/